# How to find the substring \' in string, PHP

Tags: php, string, quotes, backslash

I need to find all the `\'` from a string, and replace them with something else.
I'm using PHP.

Example: if I wanted to replace them with 4s, the original string would be

```
\b\fs\'80.\b
```

And the new one

```
\b\fs480.\b
```

Can anyone help? Thanks everybody.

Comment: a simple `str_replace("\\'", "4", $string)` should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple with [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
<?php
$string = "\b\fs\'80.\b";
$replacement = 4;
echo str_replace("\\'", $replacement, $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use regex.

```
<?php
$string = "\b\fs\'80.\b";
echo preg_replace("/\\'/", '4', $string);
```